# What Duck comic artists are officially canon?

Tags: canon, donald-duck

Carl Barks created the Duckverse. Don Rosa created "The Life and Time of Uncle Scrooge". Generally, all comics by those two artists are considered canon.

Apart from those two artists, which other artists (or stories) are considered Duck canon?

Comment: what is considered Duck canon? Especially now that there are two official 'Duck' tv shows that condradict each other

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends highly on what you consider canon. There are numerous Donald Duck stories published in Europe, mostly by Italian and Spanish artists, now under the auspices of Danish publishing house Egmont. Being official, licensed productions, they can be considered canon.

[This site](https://www.lambiek.net/comics/disneyartists.htm) has a list of all Disney comic book artists, but doesn't distinguish between Donald Duck, Mickey Mouse, and other characters.

A lot of characters that are now considered canon were created by artists other than Barks and Rosa. Dick Kinney  and Al Hubbard created Donald's cousin [Fethry Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fethry_Duck), while [Moby Duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_family_(Disney)#Moby_Duck) was created by Vic Lockman and [Tony Strobl](https://art-bin.com/art/strobleng.html) (who drew quite a lot of US Donald Duck stories.

[Al Taliaferro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Taliaferro), with writer Bob Karp, did the Donald Duck newspaper strip from 1938 to 1968 and Sunday pages from 1939 to 1969. The strips introduced in comic form (both had appeared in cartoons) Donald's cousin Gus and love interest Daisy Duck, as well as Grandma Duck, all of which must be considered canon. Taliaferro also created Donald's iconic car. Much of this happened before Carl Barks began on the comic book in 1943, and Barks used many of Taliaferro's characters. If you consider Barks canon, you hence must also consider Taliaferro canon.

A popular superheroic version of Donald Duck, [Paperinik or Duck Avenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck_in_comics#Paperinik_(Duck_Avenger)), was created by Italians Guido Martina and Giovan Battista Carpi. One of the most productive Duck-artist was Victor "Vicar" Arriagada Rios, (deceased 2012). He had his own studio where he and his assistants drew the stories sent in by Egmont.

Some fans don't consider any post-Barks stories canon except those by Rosa (and some even don't count these), while others consider all licensed stories canon. It depends on a matter of taste; I doubt that Disney has any official opinion on the matter.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Duck_in_comics) has more detail about the development of Donald Duck comics.

Answer (score 1):

Comics by [Al Taliaferro](https://www.lambiek.net/artists/t/taliaferro.htm) could be considered canon, since he and Ted Osborne created the comics that introduced Donald's nephews.

Additionally, [Tony Strobl](https://www.lambiek.net/artists/s/strobl_tony.htm) and [William Van Horn](https://www.lambiek.net/artists/v/van-horn-william.htm) made several contributions to Donald Duck and Duckverse media and could probably be considered canon as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you view the DuckVerse and continuity.

First, you have to understand that each version of the Duck world is its own continuity.

That’s a undisputed fact.

There are many minor and major differences between each incarnation of this world.

However, you can have your own headcanon, which is what you, the viewer, see as canonical.

Let’s take me for example.

Carl Barks created several characters and locations that are essential to the Ducks, so I consider his stories canon.

Ducktales (the 1987 version), despite its own creative liberties from the source material, syncs up well with Barks’ version of Duckburg, so I consider that canon.

I believe that the Life and Times of Scrooge McDuck is the canonical biography of Scrooge in all canons to some extent.

Don Rosa’s goal with his stories is to be as in-sync with Barks as possible, so they are canon.

For a headcanon to work, you need to find ways to “reconcile” elements that don’t mesh with each other.

For example, I consider Ducktales and Don Rosa’s stories to be split timelines branching from Barks’ stories, stemming from Donald’s decision to go to the navy.

Unfortunately, there are certain continuities that you can’t reconcile.

Case-in-point:

Ducktales 2017.

That canon is too different from the others to be properly fitted into the larger canon, so it’s a different timeline from everything else.

Now you know, and knowing is half the battle!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please note that answers based on any individual user's personal headcanon aren't viewed in a favourable light here. As far as canoncity is concerned, we're much more interested in what the _official_ canon is, if there is one. And we also like answers to be supported with evidence from an official source, rather than just opinion. You might want to take the [tour], to learn more about the site.

Comment: OTOH, Ducktales must be canon, because c’mon, it’s Ducktales.

Comment: "First, you have to understand that each version of the Duck world is its own continuity.

That’s a undisputed fact.

There are many minor and major differences between each incarnation of this world."

If you would expand on this point with evidence, and drop the rest, it would be a great answer.